# A question about datapath

Tags: digital-logic

What is the SI input doing in the shifter?

[image]

Comment: Draw diagonal arrows from the input bits of the shifter to where those values end end up in the output.  Some output bit(s) won't have a corresponding input bit, so what should be the source of their value?

Comment: my problem is that I don't understand what does SI stand for, would you mind indicating the right answer to me so that I can try to follow and figure it out?

Comment: Draw the diagram as suggested above, and you will figure it out.

Comment: sorry, I don't get what diagram i am suppose to draw. what I don't understand is SI, what don't know what does it it stand for, Selected initial? selected ?

Comment: Don't worry about what it stands for.  Shift a pattern of bits, see where you end up with unkowns, and you'll see what it *has to* be for.

Comment: First Dout is 0, then the first clock rises, Ld is off, so it is 0, second clock, Ld is on, sel is on, 0+1, 3rd clock rises, ld is on, sel is on 1+1=2, 4th clock rises, ld is off, still 2, 5th clock rises, ld is on, sel is off, shift 1, 2*2=4, sixth clock, ld is on, sel is on, 4*2=8, 7th clock rises, repeats the same, 8*2=16.

Comment: so my answer is 0 or 1 or 2 or 4 or 8 or 16, which none of the above matches. but I don't feel right.

Comment: That has nothing to do with the question you asked.  You don't get to ask for an answer to the homework/exam question here, but you can easily derive an answer to your question about the SI signal by tracing the data of a simple example and realizing what is missing.

Comment: I feel like I am running into a deeper maze.

Comment: Pick a value, say 12.  Shift it left by 1 place.  What is the answer?  You should respond that it is impossible to answer, because something is missing.  So now you have something missing, and something you do not know the purpose of. How might these be related?  (If it's not clear enough, shift 0xC *right*, and consider what the answer should be if 0xC encodes 12, vs if it encodes -4)

Comment: @horta because if you can figure out something for yourself, it doesn't matter if you forget it, as you can simply re-derive it as needed.

Comment: @Chris Stratton May I ask you to figure what does “你条扑街，玩野啊？” Without proper context, I assume you can figure it out yourself.

Comment: you're making a classic mistake.  Mathematics is universal behind the expression, which makes it easy to figure out from the context (which *is very* present here), *even when the expression is unfamiliar*.  If you and a space alien are both aware of your own version of the concepts that we call binary and shifting, then you'll also be mutually aware of the need for something like the mystery signal at issue here.

Comment: @ChrisStratton You can easily have a bit shifter that wraps around (aka https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_shift) and then you would never need SI or SO. That was the first thing that came to my mind when thinking about a bit shifter.  Once Tmm understands what the inputs to a shifter can be, if he ever forgets he can re-derive it if need be.

Comment: @horta - that's a rotate, not a shift, and it's merely a case of feeding the extra output of a shifter back to the missing input.

Comment: @ChrisStratton When it's called a "circular *shift*", I'm not sure how you can say it's not a shift. I'm sure it's also be called a rotate. And while I understand what it's doing, there's no reason for that input/output to be externally visible.

Comment: The reason for it to be externally visible is that the the same block can perform all types of shifts - those with circular rotation feedback, those of logical patterns, those of 2's complement numbers, and multi-word shifts with what is essentially a "carry" linked to or from another word.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears to be the serial input pin. Basically, if you shift bits, you can either have a wrap-around shifter or an empty hole. The serial input pin allows you to choose what you want to fill that empty hole with.
[image]

http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/sequential/seq_5.html